# Office 365 Client Object Model, Unauthorized Exception

Tags: development, office-365, client-object-model

I have been trying to read the contents of a list from a Office 365 site. I used [this link](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html) as reference.

Code:

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in Pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(_username, passWord);
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);

var query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = @"<View/>";

ListItemCollection listItems = oList.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(oList);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The only catch here is that all users log in using Facebook or Google. I've noticed that my username changes from my email to `i:0#.f|membership|" + _username`.

I get a 401 error at the last Statement.

Comment: If the users login via Google or FB, how do you get the _username and password?

Comment: The primary email that the user has registered, that's the username and the password is their facebook password. But, somehow I don't think this will work.

Comment: Hmm for you to successfully get authenticated on a SP site, the user must have permissions granted in the site. You can look into how you are going to map the google/fb user to the authenticated user in the site.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look.